# Flutter how to collapse ExpansionTile on child button click?

Tags: flutter

After hours of researching, I've come to a stressed place where I need to ask a question here.

I'm simply trying to collapse an ExpansionTile on button click but it is not working. The Expansion Tile is nested in a ListView.

```
Flexible(
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                          horizontal: 8.0, vertical: 8.0),
                      child: Container(
                        // color: white,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                          color: light == true ? yellow : blue,
                          boxShadow: [
                            BoxShadow(
                                color: light == true ? yellow : blue,
                                spreadRadius: 0),
                          ],
                        ),
                        child: ExpansionTile(
                          initiallyExpanded: false,
                          // childrenPadding: EdgeInsets.all(1),
                          key: GlobalKey(),
                          title: Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(3.0),
                            child: Row(
                              mainAxisAlignment:
                              MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                              children: [

                                Row(
                                children: [
                                Icon(
                                  Icons.wb_sunny,
                                  color: Colors.yellow, // Colors.yellow
                                  size: 28.1,
                                ),
                                Text(
                                  '  Wake up',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                      color: light == true
                                          ? blue
                                          : Colors.white,
                                      fontSize: 15.0,
                                      fontFamily: 'poppins'),
                                ),
                                ],
                                ),
                                Text(
                                  _wakeuptime_time_friendly,
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      color: light == true
                                          ? blue
                                          : Colors.white,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                      fontSize: 15.0),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Column(
                              crossAxisAlignment:
                              CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                              children: [
                                Padding(
                                  padding:
                                  const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
                                  child: _wakeup_routine_daily_bool
                                      ? Center(
                                    child: Text(
                                      'Good job!',
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          color: light ==
                                              true
                                              ? blue
                                              : Colors
                                              .white,
                                          fontWeight:
                                          FontWeight
                                              .bold,
                                          fontSize: 22.0),
                                    ),
                                  )
                                      : Column(

                                    children: [

                                      Row(
                                        mainAxisAlignment:
                                        MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                                        children: [
                                          ElevatedButton(
                                            style: light == true
                                                ? raisedButtonStyleBlue
                                                : raisedButtonStyleYellow,
                                            onPressed: () async {

                                              // db query

                                              setState(() {
                                                
                                              });

                                            },
                                            child: const Text(
                                              'Done!',
                                              style: TextStyle(
                                                  fontWeight:
                                                  FontWeight
                                                      .bold,
                                                  fontSize: 18.0),
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                          ElevatedButton(
                                            style: light == true
                                                ? raisedButtonStyleBlue
                                                : raisedButtonStyleYellow,
                                            onPressed: () async {

                                              setState(() {
                                              
                                              });

                                            },
                                            child: const Text(
                                              'Missed',
                                              style: TextStyle(
                                                  fontWeight:
                                                  FontWeight
                                                      .bold,
                                                  fontSize: 18.0),
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ],
                                      )

                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
```

With both ElevatedButton widgets in the onClick(), I'm trying to collapse ExpansionTile. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: So expansion tile is not expanding? Is this is your case? Inside ListView.builder() ?

Comment: I remember searching for that as well. But if you check the source code for `expansion_title.dart`, you see that `_isExpanded` is private and is not exposed, so it might not be possible.